# Loop audio file from the command line (gapless) or into new file

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, jack, moc

The only command line solution for gapless playback I found so far (working with ALSA and JACK) is `moc (»music on console«)`. While I'm still searching for a simpler way I was wondering if it is possible to loop an audio file into a new file for a given number of times?

Something like:

```
loop-audio infile.flac --loop 32 outfile.flac
```

for repeating `infile.flac` `32` times into `outfile.flac`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes it is just good to know that `linux-life` can be as easy as imagined, in this case by using **SoX (Sound eXchange):**

```
sox infile.flac outfile.flac repeat 32
```

this even works with different file formats like:

```
sox infile.flac outfile.mp3 repeat 32
```

would loop into a **`128 kbps` MP3**

other bit rates can be set using the option:

```
-C|--compression FACTOR  Compression factor for output format
```

getting an **320 kbps MP3** would be obtained with this command:

```
sox infile.flac -C 320 outfile.mp3 repeat 32
```

---

and finally a simple ***gapless playback*** from the command line with **mpv**:

```
mpv --loop-file infile.flac
```

or the same even simpler:

```
mpv --loop infile.flac
```

Comment: Or even simplier just in one line: play test.wav repeat 15

Comment: mpv is not gapless.

Comment: play is a bit better, but still not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and wanted *actual* gapless. I use this solution:

1. download and use [Music On Consol](https://moc.daper.net/) (moc)
2. `mocp -S && sleep 5s && mocp -o r -u s,n && mocp -l /path/to/your.file`

adapted from this [moc forum answer](https://moc.daper.net/comment/6477#comment-6477)