# Copy a same audio file multiple time in another audio file

Tags: audio, wav

I have an audio file on my Linux system. Let's say a 2 second `.wav`  file. I want to copy the same audio file 50 times into a new `b.wav` such that the duration of `b.wav` will be 100 seconds.
I tried like this:

```
for i in {1..50}; do cat a.wav >> b.wav; done
```

But it's not working. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. Got it.

```
sox a.wav b.wav repeat 50
```

Refer to this question.
[Loop audio file from the command line (gapless) or into new file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497579/loop-audio-file-from-the-command-line-gapless-or-into-new-file)